# angularjs nested routing doesn't load layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
.state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'index.html',
      abstract:true
 })
.state('home.dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'dashboard/index.html',
      controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
 })
```

I failed to load `index.html` when I visit `example.com/dashboard`, I was only able to get the raw html of what is inside `dashboard/index.html`. That's strange, because in `index.html` I've declared `<ui-view></ui-view>` within the body so I expect `dashboard/index.html` to be a child of `index.html`.

Pushed a [repo](https://github.com/eldyvoon/cart-aff) of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have nested states; you simply have a primary index.html file that serves as the container for your application, its dependencies, and your views. Angular won't load your primary index.html page, the index.html page loads Angular.

So there is no need for your 'home' state to have a templateUrl. You will use nested states if, for example, your dashboard view has an inner view that can load different templates depending on a user action. See Angular UI Router's [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-%26-nested-views) for some example use cases for nested views.

Comment: I tried this `$stateHelperProvider.setNestedState({
      name: 'app',
      templateUrl: 'index.html',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'dashboard',
          templateUrl: 'dashboard/index.html',
        }
      ]
    });` it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare index.html as your first`state` like @jakeblues said.

Try to put all the specific content from `index.html` in a new template :

```
.state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'homeCtrl'
 })
.state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'dashboard/index.html',
      controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
 })
```

Comment: I want to put my style in home.html

Comment: could you explain what you mean  ?

Comment: I want to load dashboard/index.html within layout.html, and dashboard/index.html should not contain any css or js, those should be in layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your code from the repo.

The main problem I am seeing is that your angular code is not being loaded when you do example.com/dashboard

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This makes your public folder as the folder from which the project is being loaded.

When you do example.com, Your angular code is loaded because you are responded with public/index.html file which contains angular code and it is correct.

But when you do example.com/dashboard, it is actually loading html file /public/dashboard/index.html where there is no any angular code.

Try doing alert on dashboardCtrl.js. You will get nothing because it is not being loaded. It is only included in index.html file which is not loaded at all.

Try changeing url to dashboards and remove 'home.dashboard'

```
.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboards',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard/index.html',
  controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
 })
```

Comment: so I have to put my style into dashboard/index.html?

Comment: No you don't have to put style in dashboard/index.html. Your styles can be in index.html. It is fine. Please check my response in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305398/how-to-render-template-in-route-with-params-in-express/39305597?noredirect=1#comment65944471_39305597 to deal with styles.