# How to render template in route with params in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Express and Pug template engine. I have two routes:

**/profile** which shows logged in user profile info. Can be accessed only by logged in users

**/profile/:id** which shows other user's info. Can be accessed by everyone.

Here is my code:

```
    app.get("/profile/:id", function(req,res) {
      // Get info from DB for specifed username in req.params.id
      res.render("profile.pug", locals);
    });

    app.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, function(req,res) { // isLoggedIn is middleware which checks if user is logged in
      res.render("profile.pug", locals);
    });
```

I serve my JS/CSS/images using express.static:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
```

When I browse **/profile**, everything is OK, but when I try **/profile/:id,** it renders template without styles. Morgan loggger wrote that **/profile/:id** tries to get assets not from domain root, but from /profile!

```
GET /profile/css/bootstrap.css 404 7.352 ms
```

Which should be:

```
GET /css/bootstrap.css 200 7.352 ms
```

How to fix that?

Comment: could you please also post you pug file. i think that the error is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to define another routes for such static files.

```
app.use("/static", express.static(path.resolve('./public/assets')));
```

Then you place all the css files under assets folder. After that you can use '/static/css/bootstrap.css' in the template files.

The problem I assume in your code is that it is taking profile/:id as current path.

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Maybe my mistake was that I specifed path to css in pug files like "css/boostrap.css", not "/css/bootstrap.css" (with slash on the beginning)

Comment: Yes I assumed some problem like that. Did it also work when you only add /css/boostrap.css in your original file? Cheers!